# How to display the room resources in a week view of a Full Calendar

Tags: taxonomy-terms, panels, javascript, views, bookings

I need to show the room booking in the weekly list.

I've created a node type called 'booking'.  The node has three fields, start date - end date, title and room name.  The room name is assigned as the taxonomy field.

I want to list the room booking in the calendar as below.

The full calendar is installed in my site.  The weekly calendar format is set.  Yes, it can show the booking clearly, but it can show the booking of individual room only.

I've searched both calendar and room reservation modules.  They cannot meet our requirement.

Is there any way or module to do it?   Please help.  Thanks.

[image]

After applying the views_field_view according to the comment ->
[image]

Comment: Checkout https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view using this you need to make both room/week views. In week view you need to add View field (room view) and make proper relationship (if needed) to be able to see all rooms in one view

Comment: I've tried views_field_view.  It can display the full calendars in the cells (as shown in the second image).  Is it possible to group the headers into one so that the users can change the date at once?

Comment: I've also tried to use the path view-name/fullcalendar?year=2015&month=8&day=30 to display the full calendar for a specific day (or week).  But, I don't know how to request a user to input a day and let the system automatically redirect the page to the views page.  Any experts can help?  Thanks.